# how i can fix this date issues for ios8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nscalendar, gregorian-calendar

i don't know how to write the right code to fix my date issue

```
class Date {

class func from(#year:Int, month:Int, day:Int) -> NSDate{

    var components = NSDateComponents()
    components.year = year
    components.month = month
    components.day = day

  let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    let date = gregorianCalendar?.dateFromComponents(components)

    return date!
}
```

this is the error message
 'NSGregorianCalendar' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Use NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian instead

but when i replace the next line didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

It will return you gregorian calendar (depending on locale settings).

Another option is to define constants and use GregorianCalendar as a calendar name :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    #define GregorianCalendar NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian
#else
    #define GregorianCalendar NSGregorianCalendar
#endif
```

Comment: Date calculations won't work if you use `currentCalendar` and your user is in another locale. Use @mspasov's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to force gregorian calendar use the following NSCalendar initializer:

```
        let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
```